# what does origin represent in a costmap?

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using costmap_2d c++ api. In the constructor one can set an origin of the costmap. what does this origin represent? it is a point or a cell? if i set origin e.g. (10,10) does it mean the cell to the left and below origin will have a negative index?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11377/what-does-origin-represent-in-a-costmap?/) by [harmish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1124/harmish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-09-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By resetting the costmap origin, you are telling the costmap that its position in the world frame has changed. The costmap_2d object uses the origin that you specify when calling the `mapToWorld()` method (among others) to determine the translation from world coordinates to individual costmap cells. You can set the origin in whatever frame you want.

So, if you set (10, 10) as the origin, and you sent a goal of (15, 15), when you look up the costmap grid space corresponding to your goal, the grid space would be ( (15-10) / resolution, (15-10) / resolution) ). So if your resolution was 0.1 meters/pixel, your costmap index for that goal would be (50, 50).

Additionally, the costmap grid spaces can never have a negative index (they're all `unsigned int`). You can find the API [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html) if you're interested.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-10-07**:
hello,@DimitriProsser,if i set(10,10)as the  map origin,sent a goal  of (5,5),then the goal coordinate  in the /map would be (-5/resolution,-5/resolution),then calling  `getIndex()`method,it will return negative index,conflict with the return type`unsigned int` ,where  i mistake ?

**Comment by [ashish](https://answers.ros.org/users/23237/ashish/) on 2017-01-25**:
@jxl : Goal of (5,5) would be out of the map's bounds as the map's origin is set to (10,10). Goal's x,y coordinates must be >= origin's x,y coordinates respectively.